# MySQL query to insert record into table based on records in another table

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a MySQL (5.6) query.  I'm not sure how to begin.

I have a table "blades". This table contains blade server records, including the following columns:

- enclosure_name
- bay_number
- description
- server_name
- ...

Each enclosure holds 16 blades servers in bays 1-16.

I have another table "available_bays". This table contains the following columns:

- enclosure_name
- bay_number
- status
- reserved
- reserved_by
- reserved_date

I need a query that will scan through the blades table and for each enclosure that has less than 16 blades, write a row to the available_bays table with enclosure_name and bay_number. The used enclosure bays may not be consecutive. In other words, the servers in enclosure1 may be in bays 1-8, 10, 13-16. So in this example, I would need to end up with the following records in the available_bays table:

```
enclosure_name bay_number
enclosure01 9
enclosure01 11
enclosure01 12
```

Also, it would need to insert the record in the available_bays table only if the same enclosure_name and bay_number do not already exit.

Any help on creating this query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use an `INSERT IGNORE INTO available_bays SELECT ...` query.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the work for 1 query... Sounds like you need more logic than SQL can give you.

Comment: Do you have any control over the table design? Ideally you would have a table which specified all the bays, filled or not.

Comment: The blades table data is generated by a powershell script that pulls the server data from a HP tool.  It does not have the option to insert a blank record for an empty server bay.

Comment: is it possible for a SQL query to insert records into the blades table for any enclosure/bay_number that do not already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c4328/2/1)</kbd> is an example here I am only generating available_bays for the first 3 bays, you can add in the the `UNION SELECT 4` and so on up to 16.

```
INSERT INTO available_bays(enclosure_name,bay_number)
SELECT t3.enclosure_name,t3.bay_number
FROM
  (SELECT enclosure_name,bay_number FROM
    (      SELECT 1 as bay_number
     UNION SELECT 2
     UNION SELECT 3
     UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5
     UNION SELECT 6
     UNION SELECT 7
     UNION SELECT 8
     UNION SELECT 9
     UNION SELECT 10
     UNION SELECT 11
     UNION SELECT 12
     UNION SELECT 13
     UNION SELECT 14
     UNION SELECT 15
     UNION SELECT 16)as t,
    (SELECT DISTINCT enclosure_name FROM blades)as t2
  )as t3
LEFT JOIN blades b
ON (b.bay_number = t3.bay_number AND b.enclosure_name = t3.enclosure_name)
LEFT JOIN available_bays ab
ON (ab.bay_number = t3.bay_number AND ab.enclosure_name = t3.enclosure_name)
WHERE  b.bay_number IS NULL
  AND ab.bay_number IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this query.  It works in SQL Fiddle, but I'm getting the following error when I run it in MySQL Workbench:  "Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1'"

Comment: what type is bay_number? is it a string?

Comment: Okay, I found the issue.  bay_number datatype is varchar instead of int.  So this query does exactly what I need with one exception.  If I run it multiple times, it will insert duplicate rows.  How can I modify it to not insert the row if the enclosure_name and baynumber already exist in the available_bays table?

Comment: I just added another `LEFT JOIN` and `AND ab.bay_number IS NULL` check the updated query code, this will check to see if it's not already in `available_bays` table.